# Visual Studio 2022 Docker Desktop SSL Certificate Error

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, docker-desktop

I am trying to get VS 2022, Docker Desktop and SSL working correctly

I completed the following steps

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p myPass123

dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

I get the following results

> Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A
> confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not
> previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.

my docker-compose.override file has several containers which will use the SSL

```
ocelotapigw:
    container_name: ocelotapigw
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypass123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
      - "TenantRemoteStore:Url=https://tenantstore.grpc"
    ports:
      - "9001:80"
      - "9002:443"
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro

  stripedotnet.api:
    container_name: stripedotnet.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypass123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
      - "EventBus:HostAddress=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672"
      - "TenantRemoteStore:Url=https://tenantstore.grpc"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - tenantstore.grpc
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
      - "8002:443"
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro

  razor.web:
    container_name: razor.web
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypass123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
      - "HttpClient:APIGatewayUrl=https://ocelotapigw"
      - "ElasticConfiguration:Uri=http://elasticsearch:9200"
      - "SecureTokenService:IdentityUrl=https://identity.api/DaedalSoftSports"
      - "SecureTokenService:CallBackUrl=https://razor.web/"
    depends_on:
      - ocelotapigw
      - identity.api
    ports:
      - "10008:80"
      - "10009:443"
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

When I try to run VS 2022 docker-compose I get the error below and VS 2022 stops execution

[image]

Did I miss a step? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I had Docker file that was not updated with some dependencies

Comment: What file was it and how did you detect it?